# URL Rewriting does not work

Tags: php, seo

I am trying to optimize one site with a URL like this `/category.php?show=numberID`

I want something like this: `/category/numberID/`

For example I want: `http://example.com/category.php?show=8` to become `http://example.com/category/8/`

I have Googled and come across this `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/$ /category.php?show=$1 [L]
```

What's wrong in this code, please don't send me some tutorial links because i was watched lot of them, and i just want your advice.

Comment: Please choose a useful title. "Why this don't work" isn't one.

Comment: We don't know what's wrong with it, what happens when you use it?

Comment: @RudiVisser apsolutly nothing, that is problem. :(

Comment: .. so what happens when you visit `http://example.com/category/8/`?

Comment: You don't want `category.php?show=8` "to become `category/8/`", you want `category/8/` *to resolve to `category.php?show=8`*. You type in `category/8/` and it runs as if you typed in `category.php?show=8`. That's what rewriting does.

Comment: @RudiVisser hmm some primitive look, just text, no gui?

Comment: @DocNet Right. So it does work, you're just not getting styling. See an answer..

Comment: @RudiVisser hmm cool, but how i can to style that page, and when someone visit that page that redirect him on /category/id/? Sorry for bad English.  :/

Comment: @DocNet ? See my answer and it will tell you how to get the page styled correctly.

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in comments it seems that your rewrite rule is working just fine, and your issue is with styling of the page no longer working.

The issue behind this is because, as far as your browser is concerned, you are now inside the directory `/category/8/`. This means that any relative links to styles or images etc, are going to be resolved into `/category/8/` rather than your site root. For example:

```
<img src="images/test.jpg" alt="Test" />
<script src="scripts/site.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

will be resolved to:

```
<img src="/category/8/images/test.jpg" alt="Test" />
<script src="/category/8/scripts/site.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Rather than where they should be, in the site root. The easiest way to fix this is to make all of your resource links absolute, like so (by prepending a `/`):

```
<img src="/images/test.jpg" alt="Test" />
<script src="/scripts/site.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

---

Another stop-gap solution (*far* less preferred than the above) would be to use a `<base .. />` tag, like so:

```
<base href="http://example.com/" />
```

This will tell your browser that all relative links should be resolved against that `base`.